# regular expression matching all 8 character strings except "00000000"

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to figure out a regular expression which matches any string with 8 symbols, which doesn't equal "00000000".

can any one help me?

thanks

Comment: Will your next question be on matching except "0000000000000000"...

Answer (score 12):

In at least perl regexp using a negative lookahead assertion: `^(?!0{8}).{8}$`, but personally i'd rather write it like so:

`length $_ == 8 and $_ ne '00000000'`

Also note that if you do use the regexp, depending on the language you might need a flag to make the dot match newlines as well, if you want that. In perl, that's the `/s` flag, for "single-line mode".

Comment: Christoffer - use @Marcelo and @klausbyskov to notify both about your changes ... this way they will get a real notification in their status bar and hopefully return to your answer again :) See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments

Answer (score 8):

Unless you are being forced into it for some reason, this is not a regex problem. Just use `len(s) == 8 && s != "00000000"` or whatever your language uses to compare strings and lengths.

Comment: I am using Enterprise Library Validation, where I need to add regular expression, thats I want to know how can I figure out regex.

Comment: Surely you meant `(s.length() == 8) && (s != "00000000")`?

Comment: True, and if this is a homework assignment - it needs to be specified. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you need a regex, `^(?!0{8})[A-Za-z0-9]{8}$` will match a string of exactly 8 characters. Changing the values inside the [] will allow you to set the accepted characters.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers, regular expressions are not the right tool for this task.  I suspect it is a homework, thus I'll only hint a solution, instead of stating it explicitly.

The regexp "any 8 symbols except 00000000" may be broken down as a sum of eight regexps in the form "8 symbols with non-zero symbol on the i-th position".  Try to write down such an expression and then combine them into one using alternative ("|").

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have unspecified requirements, you really don't need a regular expression for this:

```
if len(myString) == 8 and myString != "00000000":
    ...
```

(in the language of your choice, of course!)

Comment: @James: The question says "any string with 8 symbols".  But the question seriously underspecifies the problem, so who knows?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extract all eight character strings not equal to "000000000" from a larger string, you could use

```
"(?=.{8})(?!0{8})."
```

to identify the first character of each sequence and extract eight characters starting with its index.

Comment: That would only extract one character. Try `(?!0{8}).{8}`.

Comment: @Christoffer: That was my intention. I thought maybe the OP wanted to get every eight characters matching his requirements from a larger string. Like `12345678` and `23456789` from `123456789`. I do not think this can be achieved with Regex only, but identifying the first character helps.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, one would simply check

```
if stuff != '00000000'
   ...
```

but for the record, one could easily employ
heavyweight regex (in Perl) for that ;-)

```
...
use re 'eval';

my @strings = qw'00000000 00A00000 10000000 000000001 010000';
my $L = 8;

print map "$_ - ok\n",
      grep /^(.{$L})$(??{$^Nne'0'x$L?'':'^$'})/,
      @strings;

...
```

prints

```
00A00000 - ok
10000000 - ok
```

go figure ;-)

Regards

rbo

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't ([1-9]**|\D*){8} do it? Or am I missing something here (which is actually just the inverse of ndim's, which seems like it oughta work).

I am assuming the characters was chosen to include more than digits.

Ok so that was wrong, so Professor Bolo did I get a passing grade? (I love reg expressions so I am really curious).

```
>>> if re.match(r"(?:[^0]{8}?|[^0]{7}?|[^0]{6}?|[^0]{5}?|[^0]{4}?|[^0]{3}?|[^0]2}?|[^0]{1}?)", '00000000'):
    print 'match'
... 
>>> if re.match(r"(?:[^0]{8}?|[^0]{7}?|[^0]{6}?|[^0]{5}?|[^0]{4}?|[^0]{3}?|[^0]{2}?|[^0]{1}?)", '10000000'):
...     print 'match'
match
>>> if re.match(r"(?:[^0]{8}?|[^0]{7}?|[^0]{6}?|[^0]{5}?|[^0]{4}?|[^0]{3}?|[^0]{2}?|[^0]{1}?)", '10011100'):
...     print 'match'
match
>>>
```

That work?

Comment: Right, isn't it to match any string that is *not* 00000000? Which 100000000 is not and is picked up by my regex. Or correct me.

Comment: First of all, your regexp doesn't match e.g. 11101111.  Second of all, due to the asterisk the regexp matches strings of any length.

Comment: @zenWeasel It's still wrong, since it matches 123 and 123456789.  Only 8-character long strings should be matched (excluding 00000000).

Comment: Ah well. Thanks for checking my work anyway. Good exercise. I'll get it yet. :)

Comment: Not sure why I deserved a down vote for making a determined effort to answer a question to which I still see no accepted response. Everybody picks on the weasel.